# Does it make any statistical sense to subtract / add RMSE from the predicted results to make the model more accurate?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, modeling, rms

If RMSE represents the standard deviation of the residuals (prediction errors), while  residuals are a measure of how far from the regression line data points are, does it make any sense to subtract / add RMSE to the predicted results as some sort of adjustment to make the model more accurate?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This seems like a great idea to test out in a simulation.

Comment: Let's try out this idea.  I have a dataset of weights of human adult males.  They average 70 Kg with a standard deviation (RMSE) of 25 Kg.  Which do you think would be the better prediction of the weight of any given adult male: 70 Kg or 70 - 25= 45 Kg?  This simple example raises intriguing questions.  For instance, since residuals tend equally to be above and below the correct values, why shouldn't we instead *add* the RMSE to our predictions?  And why should we choose the RMSE itself--why not add or subtract, say, twice or three times the RMSE?

Comment: @whuber these are very interesting questions. This is what I was wondering. But the results from the R Script below seems to indicate that adding / subtracting RMSE doesn't make the prediction more accurate. But does standard deviation affects the use of the proposed method? Maybe it's a case by case basis?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  They only way to improve the prediction is to improve the model.  There's no "free lunch" to be had by adjusting the predictions in this *ad hoc* manner.

Comment: And that's because you don't know by how much or in what direction you should adjust the prediction unless you know the true value, and if you know the true value, you shouldn't be trying to predict it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simulate this and see what happens.

```
set.seed(2022)

# Define sample size
#
N <- 100 

# Define predictor variable
#
x <- sort(runif(N, -2, 2))

# Define y
#
y <- 3 - x + rnorm(N, 0, 1) 

# Fit linear model
#
L <- lm(y ~ x) # Fit linear model

# Calculate RMSE
#
rmse <- sqrt(mean((predict(L) - y)^2)) # Calculate RMSE

# # Add/subtract the RMSE to/from the predicted values
#
adjusted_predictions <- predict(L) + sample(c(-1, 1), N, replace = T)*rmse 

# Calculate the RMSE of the adjusted predictions
#
adjusted_rmse <- sqrt(mean((adjusted_predictions - y)^2)) 

rmse # I get ~1.066
adjusted_rmse # I get ~ 1.57, which is greater than the original RMSE

# Let's do it many times

# Define the number of times to try the prediction adjustment
#
R <- 1000 
adjusted_rmses <- rep(NA, R) # Blank vector to hold RMSE values

# Loop
for (i in 1:R){ 
    
    # Add/subtract the RMSE to/from the predicted values
    #
    adjusted_predictions <- predict(L) + sample(c(-1, 1), N, replace = T)*rmse 
    
    # Calculate the RMSE of the adjusted predictions
    #
    adjusted_rmses[i] <- sqrt(mean((adjusted_predictions - y)^2)) 
    
}

mean(adjusted_rmses) # I get ~ 1.50, which is greater than the original RMSE
```

Your proposed methodology results is *weaker* performance, not stronger.

I think I see why you would expect it to be better, however. If you know that the average amount by which the model misses the truth is the RMSE (not quite what RMSE means, but it's close), then adjust the prediction, right? The trouble is that, since we don't know the truth when we make predictions for real (if we did, there would not be anything to predict), we have to guess about adding or subtracting the value by which we are adjusting the prediction.

If we guess right, then we improve performance, but if we guess wrong, we lower performance. Interestingly, having equal numbers of right and wrong guesses seems not to cancel out to result in equal performance.

Further, we can overshoot the true value, even if we move in the right direction. For instance, if the prediction is lower than the observation and we guess that we should increase the prediction, we might wind up with a larger residual. As an example, consider an $RMSE$ adjustment of $10$, for a true value of $5$ and a prediction of $4$. We guess that our prediction is low, so we add $10$ to get an adjusted prediction of $14$, but now our residual has a magnitude of $9$ instead of $1$.

**NOW LET'S PROVE IT**

My simulation assumes a model of $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x +\epsilon_i$ for $iid$ $\epsilon_i$. $$RMSE = \sqrt{\mathbb E\left[\epsilon_i^2\right]} = \sqrt{\mathbb E\left[\left(Y_i - \hat Y_i\right)^2\right]}$$

I am going to drop the square root so I don't have to keep writing it, but if we show that $MSE_{original}<MSE_{adjusted}$, then $RMSE_{original}<RMSE_{adjusted}$.

Let $\tilde Y_i = \hat Y_i + Z_i$ be an adjusted prediction, where $Z_i$ takes $\pm RMSE$ with equal probability. Note that $Z_i$ has positive variance and zero expected value, so its second moment is equal to its variance. $\hat Y_i$ and $Z_i$ are independent, so when we get to the step in the proof where we calculate $\mathbb E\left[\hat Y_iZ\right]$, [we can take that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667911/expected-value-of-the-product-of-functions-of-two-independent-random-variables) as $\mathbb E\left[\hat Y_i\right]\mathbb E\left[Z\right]$.

The $MSE$ of the adjusted predictions is $\mathbb E\left[
\left(
Y_i - \tilde{Y_i}
\right)^2
\right]$.

$$
=
\mathbb E\left[
Y_i^2 - 2Y_i\tilde Y_i + \tilde Y_i^2
\right]\\=
\mathbb E\left[
Y_i^2 -2Y_i(\hat Y_i + Z_i) + (\hat Y_i + Z_i)^2
\right]\\=
\mathbb E\left[
Y_i^2 - 2Y_i\hat Y_i -2Y_iZ_i + \hat Y_i^2 + 2\hat Y_i Z_i + Z_i^2
\right]\\=
\mathbb E\left[
Y_i^2 - 2Y_i\hat Y_i+\hat Y_i^2 -2Y_iZ_i+2\hat Y_iZ_i + Z_i^2
\right]\\=
\mathbb E\left[
(Y_i -\hat Y_i)^2-2Y_iZ_i+2\hat Y_iZ_i + Z_i^2
\right]\\=
\mathbb E\left[
\left(
Y_i - \hat{Y_i}
\right)^2
\right] - 2\mathbb E\left[Y_i Z_i\right] + \mathbb E\left[\hat Y_i Z_i\right] + \mathbb E\left[Z_i^2\right]
$$

Since $Y_i$ is a constant, we can pull it out of the expectation.

$$
=
\mathbb E\left[
\left(
Y_i - \hat{Y_i}
\right)^2
\right] - 2Y_i \mathbb E\left[Z_i\right] + \mathbb E\left[\hat Y_i Z_i\right] + \mathbb E\left[Z_i^2\right]
\\=
\mathbb E\left[
\left(
Y_i - \hat{Y_i}
\right)^2
\right] - 2Y_i \mathbb \times 0 + \mathbb E\left[\hat Y_i\right]\mathbb E\left[Z\right] + \mathbb E\left[Z_i^2\right]
\\=
\mathbb E\left[
\left(
Y_i - \hat{Y_i}
\right)^2
\right] - 2Y_i \mathbb \times 0 + \mathbb E\left[\hat Y_i\right]\times 0 + \mathbb E\left[Z_i^2\right]
\\=
\mathbb E\left[
\left(
Y_i - \hat{Y_i}
\right)^2
\right] + \mathbb E\left[Z_i^2\right] 
\\>\mathbb E\left[
\left(
Y_i - \hat{Y_i}
\right)^2
\right] = MSE_{original}\\\square
$$

Comment: Thank you for providing the R code to realistically test the concept. But as you said, it really depends on if we "guest" right or wrong. When I remove the seed value and run the code several times, the adjusted RMSE is "always" higher than the original RMSE. I know I can't generalize the results with these few trials. But is there statistical proof that this is always the case? If not, what's the probability that we actually "guess" right, which leads to improved performance.

Comment: I also realized this interesting obseveration: "having equal numbers of right and wrong guesses seems not to cancel out to result in equal performance." But I just can't figure out why is that the case. Maybe I should open another question for this.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe let's open a separate question just to seek for the complete proof above? Or at least some validation once it's completed?

Comment: @AvivLo The last little bit about the expectation of $\hat Y Z$ completes the proof. I’ll tidy it up tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for the proof. It's a solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question indicates that you are thinking about the sampling variability for the parameter estimates in the model that you would obtain from a sample data set.  And, while we cannot make a single prediction "more accurate", your idea of improving the model may be restated as ¿can we add more confidence to our predictions with the rmse?  (If I have completely misrepresented your query, please let me know.)

The answer is:  yes.  And your intuition that it would involve the rmse is essentially spot on.  But, the manner in which we add/subtract this value is a bit convoluted.

I will provide here the formula you would use for a bivariate regression model (one scalar predictor and one scalar response variable).  If you imagine starting with your bivariate regression model, you can make a point-estimate prediction:
$$\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 · x_0$$
Now, if you want to add confidence to this prediction, we will add/subtract the rmse...but we also have to account for some of the variability in our estimates for the slope and intercept.  To update the estimate, we have the following formula:
$$\hat{y} = \left(\beta_0 + \beta_1 · x_0\right) \pm t_\text{c.v.}·\text{rmse}·\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_0 - \bar{x})^2}{s_x^2(n-1)}}$$
where $t_\text{c.v.}$ is the critical value associated with the degree of confidence you wish to have in your final estimate, $n$ is the sample size, $\bar{x}$ is the mean of the independent variable, and $s_x$ is the standard deviation of the independent variable.

Note, the 1 under the square root is multiplied by the rmse, and this captures the idea that you were suggesting in your post.

I hope this was useful.

Comment: I do not see how this gives a better point estimate. Perhaps you could explain that in more detail.

Comment: Sorry...I updated the word "parameter" in the 1st ¶ to "prediction"...we can't make the point estimate more accurate...thus, we can't give a better point estimate...but we can give an interval estimate.

Comment: I’ll defer to the OP as to the original intent, but my read of the question was that the hope was to take the point estimates and either add or subtract the RMSE in hopes of getting point estimates closer to the observed values.

Comment: Agreed.  If this is not the OP's intention, I'll delete the response.

Comment: I am fairly new to statistics. Let me apologize first if my question is not so clear. @Dave and Gregg H, the difference between both of your interpretations of my question seems to be very subtle. But doesn't getting the point estimates closer to the observed values (Dave) help increase the overall confidence in our predictions (Gregg)?